# Random Cake Bake

Tags: code-golf

Warning: This is a bit lengthy

I have decided to build my own random function I call it "**Random Cake**"

This function should get an integer value between 0 and 99999

***Ingredients***

```
 1 x DateTime function
 1 x Sin : Radians
 1 x Absolute Value
 1 x π
 a dash of multiplication, division and addition
```

Here is the recipe

***Recipe***

> Get Current Date and Time ..... (1)

```
 "23/05/2019 17:39:42.631"
```

Break it into milliseconds, seconds, minutes, hours, days, months, and years

> Add 1 to the milliseconds ..... (2)

```
 1 + 631 = 632
```

> Add 1 to the seconds ..... (3)

```
 1 + 42 = 43
```

> Multiply both results in (2) & (3) and stir ..... (4)

```
632 * 43 = 27,176
```

> Divide the result from (4) by 360 and then Use the Sin (Rad not degrees) where Sin(π) = 0 and Sin(π/2) = 1 ..... (5)

```
 27,176 / 360 = 75.48888889
 Sin(75.48888889) in Rad = 0.09054103861
```

> then multiply step 5 result by 1000 ..... (6)

```
 0.09054103861 * 1000 = 90.54103861
```

Note this value might be negative, no problem here

Keep this in the fridge until it cools down

> In another bowl we add 3 to the Hours and multiply by the minutes .....
>   (7)

```
 (3 + 17) * 39  = 780
```

> Now we add last step's results (7) to the cooled mix in step (6)  .....
>   (8)

```
 780 + 90.54103861 = 870.54103861
```

We are almost there, be patient

> Get the absolute value of step (8) as it could be negative ..... (9)

```
 Abs(870.54103861) = 870.54103861
```

and add the flavor of the recipe which is

> The first 2 digits (without leading zeroes) in the result of step (9)
>   will represent the location of our flavor, which is the 5 digits of π after that position in the decimal representation of π..... (10)

For example:

```
Here is the value of π: 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128481

 Results of step (9) was 870.54103861
 First 2 non zero digits are 87
 So we go to digit number 87 after the decimal point in π for the length of 5 digits 
 which is 48253

 if your result was 0.001045678 then your 2 non zero digits are 10
 the point is the number does not start with 0 
 so if your number anything like 0.000012345 then plz ignore all initial zeros till you get to the meat > 0
```

in some languages you get more accurate than the other so I think you have to complete the rest of the digits manually :)

if your language gives you π = 3.14 then you have to add 159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230... to it

> Add the number in step (10) to the result in step (9) ..... (11)

```
 48253 + 870.54103861 = 49,123.54103861
```

***Decoration***

> Multiply day and month with the end result in step (11) ..... (12)

```
 23 *5 * 49,123.54103861 = 5,649,207.21944015
```

> Ignore decimals and flip the value you got ..... (13)

```
5,649,207.21944015 ==> 5,649,207 ==> 7029465
```

> Just take first 5 digits of this number ...... (14)

```
7029465 ==> 70294
```

Put it in the oven and serve warm

and that is our random number

Bon Appétit...

another example

another test case

```
Step 1 :
Date Time = "23/07/2016 04:59:31.407"


Step 2 :
1 + 407 = 408

Step 3 :
1 + 31 = 32

Step 4 :
408 * 32 = 13,056

Step 5 :
13,056 / 360 = 36.26666667
Sin(36.26666667) = -0.9904447352


Step 6 :
-0.9904447352 * 1000 = -990.4447352


Step 7 :
(3 + 04) * 59 = 413

Step 8 :
413 + (-990.4447352) = -577.4447352

Step 9 :
Abs(-577.4447352) = 577.4447352

Step 10 :
First 2 digits (without leading zeroes) ==> 57
π Position 57 (5 numbers)==> 49445

Step 11 :
49445 + 577.4447352 = 50,022.4447352

Step 12 :
50,022.4447352 * 23 * 07 = 8,053,613.6023672

Step 13 :
8,053,613.6023672 ==> 8,053,613
8,053,613 ==> 3163508

Step 14 :
First 5 Number 3163508 ==> 31635
```

Comment: Feels like this could've been sandboxed first since it's an arbitrary fixed algorithm... also, `multiply by the muints`... what are `muints`?

Comment: muints is part of a group of words we call it "Typos". it is derived from the word minutes. it is like spices to the recipe..

Comment: Can you add more test cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 50 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
žd₄/îžc>*360/Å½₄*ža3+žb*+ÄDþ0K2£žss.$5£J+žežfPïR5£
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L6UR00t@ofXHd2XbKdlbGagf7j10F6gkNbRfYnG2kf3JWlpH25xObzPwNvo0OKj@4qL9VRMDy32AsqkHt2XFnB4fRCQ@/8/AA)

**Explanation:**

```python
žd              # Push current microseconds
  ₄/            # Divide by 1000
    î           # Round up (we now have milliseconds + 1) (2)
žc>             # Push current seconds + 1 (3)
*               # Multiply both with each other (4)
360/            # Divide it by 360
    Å½          # Get the sine of this (5)
₄*              # Multiply by 1000 (6)
ža3+            # Push the current hours + 3
    žb*         # Multiply it with the current minutes (7)
+               # Add it to the earlier number (8)
Ä               # Get the absolute value of this (9)
D               # Duplicate it
 þ              # Only leave the digits of the copy, removing the decimal dot
  0K            # Remove all 0s
    2£          # Only leave the first two digits
      žs        # Push an infinite list of PI digits
        s       # Swap to get the number of two digits to the top of the stack
         .$     # Remove that many leading digits from PI
           5£   # And then only leave the first 5 digits of the remainder of PI
             J  # Join the digits together to a single string/integer (10)
+               # Add it to the earlier number that we've duplicated (11)
že              # Push the current day
  žf            # Push the current month
    P           # Take the product of all three values on the stack (12)
ï               # Truncate any decimals
 R              # Reverse this integer (13)
5£              # Only leave the first five digits (14)
                # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 223 bytes

```python
import datetime,math,sympy
d=datetime.datetime.now()
x=abs(math.sin((1+d.microsecond//1e3)*-~d.second/360)*1e3+(d.hour+3)*d.minute)
print(str(int(d.day*d.month*(int(str(sympy.pi.evalf(5+int(str(x)[:2])))[-5:])+x)))[:-6:-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7LDoIwEEX3fIXLGQpFJLIg4UsIC6Q1NLGPtIPCxl9HasTV3Jwzk7lupcmaatuUdtbTSQwkSWmZ6YGmLKzarYloD8r/wdgXYLK0wy1AXOVBGYCSCa7V6G2QozWiKEpZYZq/Bf@Bqj5jukMGgk929mzX8cTMJDFxXhmCQB7iFPu3NVpraErhUN9O3Ckun8PjDld2iAW75tIjYpdfmx7ZEmOT101e9rhtHw)

-2 bytes thanks to ValueInk

Comment: [Obligatory byte save by transforming a `(1+x)` into `-~x`](https://tio.run/##PY7LDoIwEEX3fIXLGQpFJLIg4UsIC6Q1NLGPtIPCxl9HasTV3Jwzk7lupcmaatuUdtbTSQwkSWmZ6YGmLKzarYloD8r/wdgXYLK0wy1AXOVBGYCSCa7V6G2QozWiKEpZYZq/Bf@Bqj5jukMGgk929mzX8cTMJDFxXhmCQB7iFPu3NVpraErhUN9O3Ckun8PjDld2iAW75tIjYpdfmx7ZEmOT101e9rhtHw "Python 3 – Try It Online") (unfortunately doesn't work with the microsecond one because of the required division)

Comment: @ValueInk Right, thanks. I actually thought of that and then decided "oh it doesn't work because of the division" lmao